# Disable Keyboard :: TextInput React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The below given code is working on first time and on second time click
on same text input it is not working ( keyboard opening again ). Because the text input is already focused and i am using custom number buttons for input.

TextInput onFocus={Keyboard.dismiss()}

Any suggestions? Problem in react native.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<TextInput showSoftInputOnFocus={false}/>
```

Use showSoftInputOnFocus.
[reference](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#showsoftinputonfocus)

Answer (score 0):

use can use onKeyPress event, which gets called on every keypress on the textinput

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#onkeypress

```
<TextInput onKeyPress={Keyboard.dismiss()}/>
```

Comment: Sry wrong interpretation. I have edited my question.